# Segmentation fault - Trying to read binary file into memory

Tags: c, gcc, segmentation-fault, malloc, fread

I can't seem to load a binary file into the memory for better read performance compared to the more expensive reads to the actual file. The file is 124 MB and should be able to fit entirely into memory. This is in C, compiled by GCC 6.3 on a 84_64 GNU/Linux.

Something goes wrong when trying to access `blk*` from the `fread`.

The two malloc calls that I tried are:

```
uint8_t *blk = malloc(sizeof(uint8_t) * fileSize + 1);
uint8_t *blk = (uint8_t *) malloc(sizeof(uint8_t) * fileSize + 1);
```

And checked to see if `malloc` returned NULL but it didn't.

```c
        FILE *file = fopen("path", "rb");

        fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END); 
        long fileSize = ftell(file);

        if (ftell(file) != EOF) {
            printf("Ftell not EOF);
        }

        fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

        uint8_t *blk = malloc(sizeof(uint8_t) * fileSize + 1);

        if (file != NULL) {
            printf("File Not NULL and %d\n", fileSize);
        }
        if (blk) {
            printf("Not NULL\n");
        } else {
            printf("NULL\n");
        }

        fread(blk, 1, fileSize, file);
        fclose(file);

        printf("blk: %p | %d\n", *&blk, blk);
```

The output is:

```
    Ftell not EOF
    File Not NULL and 134215964
    blk: 0x7fffffffdcc0 | -9024 
    Not NULL
    Segmentation fault
```

Print format might be wrong but it shouldn't matter for a segmentation error.

Comment: You can instrument this deeper than that. Like, say, checking that `fopen` succeeded. Checking that `fseek`s succeeded; that `ftell` didn't return EOF (typically -1, think about what *that* does to that little size equation of yours). Never assume IO works. Assumption is the mother of all....

Comment: GCC doesn't give a warning or error about `uint8_t blk*`?

Comment: All the other parts work, I'm pretty sure the error is in the malloc or fread line @WhozCraig

Comment: Changes absolutely *nothing* I mentioned. There are six points of error in this code, and only one of them is actually instrumented (and even that isn't functionally accounted for; the code marches into undefined behavior in the event `blk` is NULL after reporting as much). A *debugger* and/or better instrumentation is needed, preferably the former, but the latter will suffice if the coverage is strong.

Comment: Except that `fread(blk, 1, 1, file);` only reads one byte from `file` into `blk`. Far less than `fileSize + 1` bytes... Also, given your uncertainty, there is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714) Please also output the result of `ls -al path`.

Comment: consider mmap() if you want performance.

Comment: Check `file != NULL` And print value of variable `fileSize`. And in malloc you no need +1 because this isnt string, dont terminate by '\0'

Comment: Added checks for the problems mentioned and returned no error @WhozCraig.

Comment: Reading 1 byte into a +1 byte memory array shouldn't return a segmentation error right? Changed the code and still have the same error. Path is just a placeholder here, it's correctly stated in the program @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: It would if you call to `mailloc` failed. Your call to `fread(blk, 1, fileSize, file);` looks better, and you can now add `blk[fileSize] = 0;` to in effect *nul-terminate* the buffer allowing you to iterate over it as you would a string (it's a bit of a convenience hack)

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't figured it out yet, your segmentation fault is cause by:

```
 printf("blk: %p | %d\n", *&blk, blk);
```

Due to your attempt to print `blk` (a pointer to `uint8_t`) as an *integer*. A mismatch between argument types and the `printf` format specifier invokes *Undefined Behavior*.

> [C11 Standard - 7.21.6.1 The fprintf
>   function(p9)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p9) `"
>   If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.
>   If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding
>   conversion specification, the behavior is undefined."`

Note also, you use of `'*&'` before `blk` in that statement is superfluous. It is simply `blk`. Dereferencing the address of a pointer is simply the pointer itself. You can correct your statement to print the pointer address and first byte in `blk` by using the proper exact width macros from `inttypes.h`, e.g.

```
printf("blk: %p | 0x%02" PRIx8 "\n", (void*)blk, *blk);
```

In your allocation, there is no need for `fileSize + 1`, unless you expect to use a hack to affirmatively *nul-terminate* `blk` so it can be used as a string. It can be convenient in some cases, but it's not generally recommended. When `ftell` returns the number of bytes in the file, that's all you need to allocate for, unless you plan on adding something at the end. Further, `sizeof(uint8_t)` like `sizeof(char)` is always `1` - it too is superfluous, e,g,

```
    if (!(blk = malloc (filesize))) {       /* validate allocation */
        perror ("malloc-blk");
        return 1;
    }
```

Further, WhozCraig was trying to convey to you that each step should be validated. With proper validation, there isn't any question where the code is failing. Adding validations to each step would look something similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    uint8_t *blk;
    long filesize;
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    if (fseek (fp, 0, SEEK_END) == -1) {    /* validate seek end */
        perror ("fseek-SEEK_END");
        return 1;
    }
    if ((filesize = ftell (fp)) == -1) {    /* validate ftell */
        perror ("ftell-fp");
        return 1;
    }
    if (fseek (fp, 0, SEEK_SET) == -1) {    /* validate seek set */
        perror ("fseek-SEEK_SET");
        return 1;
    }

    if (!(blk = malloc (filesize))) {       /* validate allocation */
        perror ("malloc-blk");
        return 1;
    }

    if (fread (blk, 1, filesize, fp) != (size_t)filesize) { /* validate read */
        perror ("fread-blk");
        return 1;
    }

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file if not stdin */

    /* do what you need with blk here */
    printf("blk: %p | 0x%02" PRIx8 "\n", (void*)blk, *blk);

    free (blk);
}
```

(**note:** don't forget to `free (blk);` when you are done with its use)

**Example Use/Output**

Running the code as-is against any file will simply output the pointer address for `blk` and the first byte in the file in 2-digit hex, e.g.

```
$ ./bin/rdfileintoblk ../dat/captnjack.txt
blk: 0x17e9240 | 0x54
```

Look things over and let me know if you have any questions.